# RoyalSlider events - how?

Tags: jquery, events, slider

How do I hide a div with jQuery using a RoyalSlider event? 
Basically, when the slider moves to the next slide I want to hide another div on the page.

I dont understand how to use the events detailed on this page: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/documentation/#api

At the moment my options for the slider look like this - but nothing happens:

```
<script id="addJS">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#slider-with-blocks-1').royalSlider({
    arrowsNav: true,
    autoPlay:{
      enabled:true,
      delay: 6000
    },
    arrowsNavAutoHide: true,
    fadeinLoadedSlide: false,
    controlNavigationSpacing: 0,
    controlNavigation: 'none',
    imageScaleMode: 'fill',
    imageAlignCenter:false,
    blockLoop: true,
    loop: true,
    numImagesToPreload: 6,
    transitionType: 'fade',
    keyboardNavEnabled: true,
    block: {
      delay: 400
    }
  });

  slider.ev.on('rsAfterSlideChange', function(event) {

    $( ".hidden1" ).fadeOut('slow');

  });
});
</script>
```

I want to fade out the div called 'hidden1' when the slider moves to the next frame.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Looks like you missed the `var slider = $(".royalSlider").data('royalSlider');` line in the documentation, unless you've defined `slider` elsewhere and just didn't include it in this snippet.

Comment: Crikey, that worked. Thanks Jason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are close! just missing the following:

```
var mySliderInstance = $('#slider-with-blocks-1').royalSlider({
    arrowsNav: true,
    autoPlay:{
      enabled:true,
      delay: 6000
    },
    arrowsNavAutoHide: true,
    fadeinLoadedSlide: false,
    controlNavigationSpacing: 0,
    controlNavigation: 'none',
    imageScaleMode: 'fill',
    imageAlignCenter:false,
    blockLoop: true,
    loop: true,
    numImagesToPreload: 6,
    transitionType: 'fade',
    keyboardNavEnabled: true,
    block: {
      delay: 400
    }
  }).data("royalSlider"); // assign the RS to a variable

  mySliderInstance.ev.on('rsAfterSlideChange', function(event) {

    $( ".hidden1" ).fadeOut('slow');

  });
```